# python try...except in handling argument from user input

Tags: python, exception, io, try-catch, argparse

my python file would read two files from command line using argparse.
I want to use 'try...except...' to handle incorrect user input, like non-exist file and incorrect command:
for example, I use '-f' to open file, then '-g' is incorrect command.

my codes are:

```
> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "Handle with input 
files")
parser.add_argument('-m', dest = "model", type=argparse.FileType('r'))
parser.add_argument('-t', dest = "test", type=argparse.FileType('r'))
parser.add_argument('-d', dest = "permute",type=argparse.FileType('r'))
args = parser.parse_args()

# Parse file names from command line

model_file = open(args.model.name)
test_file = open(args.test.name)
decoy_file = open(args.permute.name)
```

I try to implement 'try...except' in my code but failed. Here is what I did:

```
> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "Handle with input 
files")
parser.add_argument('-m', dest = "model", type=argparse.FileType('r'))
parser.add_argument('-t', dest = "test", type=argparse.FileType('r'))
parser.add_argument('-d', dest = "permute",type=argparse.FileType('r'))
args = parser.parse_args()

# Parse file names from command line
try:
model_file = open(args.model.name)
test_file = open(args.test.name)
decoy_file = open(args.permute.name)
except IOError:
print('Wrong file name')
```

Comment: What trouble are you having implementing try-except? I don't see it in your code. I don't see `-f` or `-g` either...

Comment: Just an example, in my case should be '-m', '-t', '-d'... and thanks for remind, I will clarify that in the question

Comment: With `FileType` the file is opened by the parser.  You shouldn't try to open them again.  Alternatively just accept the names (with default `str` type), and do your own `open` (preferably in a `with` context).

Comment: It's not a `IOError` but a `TypeError` for  `argparse.FileType('r')` make your `args.model`  a `stream` object already. So it will raise `expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper` when you call `open` function

Comment: So I just need to replace IOError by TypeError?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding something like this to make sure all arguments are there. Also `argparse.FileType('r')` will already open the file (meaning you can do something like `args.model.readlines()`).

```
if not all([args.model, args.test, args.permute]):
    print("All Arguments are required")
    exit(1)
```

Comment: thank you so much for helping! But using try..except is actually the requirement...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the error happend at `args = parser.parse_args()` when it parse your command param.

As we can see from `argparse's origin code`:

```
    ...
    def parse_args(self, args=None, namespace=None):
        args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
        if argv:
            msg = _('unrecognized arguments: %s')
            self.error(msg % ' '.join(argv))
        return args
    ...
    def error(self, message):
        """error(message: string)

        Prints a usage message incorporating the message to stderr and
        exits.

        If you override this in a subclass, it should not return -- it
        should either exit or raise an exception.
        """
        self.print_usage(_sys.stderr)
        args = {'prog': self.prog, 'message': message}
        self.exit(2, _('%(prog)s: error: %(message)s\n') % args)
        # exit here ,that's why can not catch the exception
```

So when you input incorrectly, like what you mentioned above, like `non-exist file` or `incorrect command` , it will call `error` function in the end, and exit the thread, that's why you cannot catch a exception by `try .. except` synax.

If you want to catch the exception, you can inherit the main class `ArgumentParser`, and rewrite the method `error`. you can take my codes as reference:

```
import argparse
import sys as _sys
from argparse import ArgumentParser


class ArgumentParserSub(ArgumentParser):
    def error(self, message):
        self.print_usage(_sys.stderr)
        args = {'prog': self.prog, 'message': message}
        raise Exception(('error: %(message)s\n') % args)


parser = ArgumentParserSub(description = "Handle with input files")
parser.add_argument('-m', dest = "model", type=argparse.FileType('r'))
parser.add_argument('-t', dest = "test", type=argparse.FileType('r'))
parser.add_argument('-d', dest = "permute",type=argparse.FileType('r'))

try:
    args = parser.parse_args()
    # Parse file names from command line
    model_file = open(args.model.name)
    test_file = open(args.test.name)
    decoy_file = open(args.permute.name)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print('Wrong file name')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! But when I try this method, it still cannot work. Only tell that 'no such file or directory' and 'model_file' is not defined.

Comment: like: python3 xxx.py -m xxx.txt -t xxx.txt -d xxx.txt

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the parser to catch and exit bad files, open the files yourself.  Just ask the parser for names, not open files.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "Handle with input files")
parser.add_argument('-m', dest = "model")    # no type
parser.add_argument('-t', dest = "test")
parser.add_argument('-d', dest = "permute")
args = parser.parse_args()
# print(args)   # good idea when debugging

# Open file names from command line
try:
    model_file = open(args.model)
    test_file = open(args.test)
    decoy_file = open(args.permute)
except IOError:
    print('Wrong file name')
```